# About CA-client in HLF Sample

Tags: client, hyperledger-fabric, ca

refer to the image below,

There is a line

```
"HFCAClient caClient = HFCAClient.createNewInstance("https://localhost:7054", props);"
```

So far, I cannot find why sample register to single URL with the props.

Because

```
"HFCAClient.createNewInstance("https://localhost:7054", props);"
```

As I know, there are 2 ORGs in the network.

I just don't know why the CAClient connect to only to ORG1. What about ORG2??

Please help.

[RegisterUser, HLF v2.2 Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZBye.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fabric-samples, they are referring to Org1 only, but you can use Org2 to register the users. You can check the issuer in the certificates and they will be pointing to Org1.

Answer (score 0):

If you download fabric-samples in latest version there is addOrg3 directory in test-network. There is a addorg3.sh file to add the Org3 in the channel along with the config file. you can follow the configuration to add the organization of your own with this template.